# How to actually implement Roles in Blazor WebApp and Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-identity, roles, .net-8.0

So, here's the thing: If you create a Blazor WebApp (.Net8) with individual accounts enabled, it will give you a working solution. For development, I'm using Sqlite. Here's what that looks like (in an otherwise **completely functional** app):

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Application.db"));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Please take note of the **Core** in `AddIdentityCore`. Now, the helptext for this method states that you simply should use `AddRole<IdentityRole>` if you want roles. An inspection of the database also yields that there are automatically created tables for roles (and claims).

However, when you add the `AddRoles<IdentityRole>` it then bombs out because the `RoleManager` service is missing. Easy fix: Just do `AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>`

Which in turn bombs out because the `RoleStore` service is missing. Okay. So I do `AddRoleStore<IdentityRole>` and everything is peachy, right?

Nope: `Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore'`

Which is weird because every other service finds the `DbContext` just fine. So, where do I go from here?

Oh, and using other things like `AddIdentity` lets the app bomb out at other locations. I'm a bit irritated because all the documentation available makes no mention of `AddIdentityCore` and also makes no mention of the necessity to add the manager and the store, instead an `AddRole` suffices in those examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting the definition of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore` I found that it has several overloads, one of which takes a `DbContext`.

For some reason the default project insists (for me) on adding everything (i.e. Roles, RoleManager and RoleStore) and throws an exception if I leave one of the three out. So the whole definition has to look like this for me:

```cs
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<IdentityRole, ApplicationDbContext>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in my test for `AddIdentityCore`

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers();
...
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
...
app.MapControllers();
```

Controller

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public ValuesController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            this._userManager = userManager;
            this._roleManager = roleManager;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAdmin()
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new()
            {
                Email = "aa@test.com",
                UserName = "aa"
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Q!q11111");
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));        
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
           
            return Ok(new { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });
        }
    }
```

Test result
[image]

Comment: That may have worked for you but with the default project it explicitly complains about the lack of a RoleStore.
As I found out, in my case I need to add an `.AddRoleStore<IdentityRole,ApplicationDbContext>()` along the other additions. I.e. the 2nd overload was the required one.

Answer (score 0):

In AddIdentityCore() you must call

```
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
```

before

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

or it won't work.